# JQuery Fade In/Out menu with Toggle

Tags: fadein, fadeout, jquery

I'm a little stuck here on how I can implement the following fade in/out menu.

I need to show menu items with fade in/out effect, however whatever I try I don't get what I'm looking for. Example:

1. User clicks on a menu "Cars". This will show cars links in a fade in fashion:
   a) Honda (fade in)
   b) Toyota (fade in 1 second later)
   c) Mitsubishi (fade in 2 seconds later)
   d) Kia (fade in 3 seconds later)
   ....
2. When user clicks on another link "Motorcycles", the website fade in menu should now start fading out from the last item (i.e. Kia).

I need the fade in/out behaviour to happen for the next item while the previous is still fading out/in. I need to achieve this gradual effect. Also, I need to have control how fast the menu items are shown/hidden.

I tried recursion i.e.

```
       function showCarMenuItems(carsDiv){
            var items =  $(carsDiv).children();     
            displayMenu(items, 0);
       }; 

       function displayMenu(items, i){
            var interval = 500;
            $(items[i]).fadeIn(interval, function(){
                if(i < items.length)
                {
                    displayMenu(items, i++);
                }
            });

        }
```

Even though it gave me a close behaviour, the display of items were not gradual as I need. That is, once the first car item fully appeared then the next one showed etc. I need as one car item is almost shown the other one should have started showing already (fading in).

Please help.

Thanks,
partizan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the `delay` method in jQuery, should be what you need.

[delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Perhaps change the code to something like:

```
   function showCarMenuItems(carsDiv){
        var items =  $(carsDiv).children();     
        displayMenu(items);
   }; 

   function displayMenu(items, i){
        var interval = 500;
        var nextInterval = 400;
        $(items).each(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(interval).delay(nextInterval); //will start the fadeIn, but wait 400 before moving on
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a callback function to `.fadeIn()`, the callback executes after the animation is complete. You need to be a little trickier about it:

```
function showCarMenuItems(carsDiv) {
    $(carsDiv).children().each(function(i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.fadeIn(5000);
        }, 500*i);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sRsTB/

---

#### Edit

As [@CnTwo points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519808/jquery-fade-in-out-menu-with-toggle/5519844#5519844), you can also do this using `.delay()` (it's definitely cleaner than my original version):

```
function showCarMenuItems(carsDiv) {
    $(carsDiv).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(500*i).fadeIn(5000);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/K6mRv/

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery `.delay()` function.

```
function showCarMenuItems(carsDiv) {
    var index = 0;

    $(carsDiv).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(2000*index++).fadeIn(7000);
    });

}

$('#cars').click(function() {
    showCarMenuItems(this);
});
```

In the example below every span's fade-in takes 7 seconds to complete and every fade-in starts 2 second before it's successor.

This means:

```
   MODEL     STARTS  ENDS    
 - Honda        2     9    
 - Toyota       4     11    
 - Mitsubishi   6     13    
 - Kia          8     15
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/krmby/m4LPE/](http://jsfiddle.net/krmby/un2tP/)